# Post a pyplot image to Slack

Tags: python, matplotlib, slack-api

How can I send an image created by pyplot to a Slack channel? Saving it locally and then try to pass the local file as an `image_url` does not work

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as pyplot
from slacker import Slacker

slack = Slacker("supersecretkey")
fig, ax = pyplot.subplots(figsize=(8,6))

ax.plot([1,2], [4,2])
fig.savefig("C:\file.png")

attachments = [{"title": "test",
                "image_url": "C:\file.png"}]
slack.chat.post_message("@mathias", "TEXT_TEST", "TEST", attachments=attachments)
```

Does unfortunately not work.

I also tried uploading the file

```
slack.files.upload("C:\file.png")
```

and used the `permalink_public` (from the result of above command) in the `attachment`, to no avail:

[image: empty message :(]

How can I solve this without too much hassle (e.g. upload to external image hoster)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The trick is the indeed use `slack.files.upload`, but immediately put it in a channel:

```
slack.files.upload("C:\file.png", channels="@slackbot")
```